# a simple Ember.Select with a default selection

Tags: ember.js

Every example I see, has a complex object for the selection (id, name etc.)

I'm trying to do a really simple thing and still can't.

The Select:
`{{view Ember.Select content=resultsPerPage selection=perPage}}`

The controller (ember-cli):

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  perPage: 10,
  resultsPerPage: ['10', '20', '50', '100'],
});
```

All I want now is for the Select to have a default value of 10, can't make it happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values in the array are strings and the the perPage value is a number. It should both be of the same type.

[Here is a working example.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jolezagabe/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

A side note - as of Ember 1.8, the use of

```
{{view Ember.Select ... }}
```

was deprecated (see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_global-lookup-of-views))

Instead, you should be using

```
{{view "select" ... }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip... still using 1.7 :)